# Reading data over serial from an old punched tape reader

Tags: serial

I have an old GNT-4601 punched tape reader/punch that I'm trying to connect to a modern computer. Using the DTE port and a [usb-to-serial adapter](https://tripplite.com/usb-serial-adapter-cable-5-feet~U209005DB25), I'm able to send data to the punch but I can't read anything back. Py-serial gives a single `b'\x00'` on `read`

I suspect that I may be using the type of wrong cable. The machine uses RS-232C with a DB-25 connector. Here is the manual with more information: 
https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_gntGNT46012_1858526/GNT_4601_Operators_Manual_Jun82#page/n7/mode/2up

Any suggestions on what to try or how to debug the problem?

Comment: Have you tried a null-modem: switch pins 2&3, 4&5, 7&20.

Comment: @cup punching works, therefore the pins are not swapped.

Comment: Are you asserting DSR?  That manual states that you must set it in order to read.  Your cable must have the DSR pin connected and your software must assert it.

Comment: @Chenmunka you mean DTR, don't you?

Comment: @berendi:  No.  I mean DSR - Data Set Ready..

Comment: @Chenmunka DSR is an input on PC serial ports. No communication software in the world can assert an input. The computer is always DTE, the reader in local mode plays the role of the DCE. [DSR is defined as input on DTE and output on DCE.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Pinouts)

Comment: In addition to the answers you've already got, newer serial adapters, esp. USB, often have voltage issues when used to interface to old equipment - RS232 used +/-12V back then, though +/-5V is in spec, which is why newer adapters use those. So get a voltmeter and measure, and try a voltage converter if you get only 5V.

Comment: Voltage would only cause problems sending, not receiving. All RS-232 ports (though not all UARTs!) are tolerant of the full +/-12V range.

Comment: Regardless of the terminology, DSR/DTR is a hardware handshake signal and it isn't implemented in all (or even most) USB adapters. You can rewire the pin though to force it on.

Comment: If you don't already have one, you may want to get a RS232 Breakout Box. I have (or used to have) a bunch of these https://www.amazon.com/Breakout-Box-RS232-Serial-Tester/dp/B076BXY47P which let you easily test every pin or the simpler ones like these https://www.ebay.com/itm/DB25-Male-Female-RS232-Serial-7-LED-Multi-Line-Status-Mini-Tester-TS-R07-/272582527761 - all of which seem to have gotten expensive, probably because hardly anyone needs them now and anyone who needs one will pay the price.

Comment: What are the settings on your serial port? According to the manual (p. 3-4/5), you can't exceed 1200bps and need at least 1 stop bit, and may possibly need a parity bit as well.

Comment: I've been using it with switches 4, 5, 6, and 7 on at medium speed. 300 baud, 8bits, no parity, one stop bit. I've tried changing the switches too but didn't have any success

Answer (score 1):

I'd first double-check that the switches are correctly set, then try looking for flow control issues.

If software flow control is selected (DC Codes and SW3 are ON), the reader waits for a DC1 (XON, decimal code 17) control character to start transmitting. In a terminal program, you can try typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

If hardware flow control is selected, ensure that your communication program sets the DTR signal.

Comment: According to the manual linked in the question, DTR is only used for punching, not for reading.  The OP states that punching works.

Comment: @Chenmunka There is a male DB-25 cable going to the female DTE port on the device. I'm assuming the device is in local mode, neither a null-modem cable nor a modem is involved. Therefore **3.5.1. a)** applies: "Reader controlled by DC1/DC3 (if selected) or **DTR**".

Comment: Ah, the joys of debugging an RS232 connection!  At least it is worth a try.

Comment: So I can send the xon signal to start the reader, I just never receive any data back. The reader itself is also acting very oddly, reading in short jerky bursts instead of smoothly like I'd expect. The whole thing could just be busted but I'm also not convinced I'm listening for data properly in the first place